# How to factory reset Xubuntu

Tags: reset

how can I factory reset my Xubuntu, deleting all files. Because my laptop becomes laggy because I added lubuntu. thanks

Comment: If you have limited ram, you want to be as efficient as possibly with your use of libraries.  If you use LXDE apps whilst your desktop in use is XFCE, you can fill your memory with libraries need to operate both (why LXDE comes with `leafpad` as an editor, XFCE comes with `mousepad`).  I suspect your issue is this (ie. you've filled your ram with libraries that do the same thing for different calling apps thus causing paging of memory to disk).  This isn't an issue with enough memory (4gb or more usually).  I suspect this is your issue.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` for a package will cause a package's post-install script to re-run; but I don't think that is your issue. When new, a full switch from XFCE to LXDE is probably simpler as you won't know which programs belong to which environment (or may not have the discipline to stick to one app) than having both as options and selecting at login.  *for readers, most of this is from prior questions; and relates to the 1gb ram machine I believe question is about*

Comment: my computer has only 1 GB of ram. Is there any option to factory reset it by wiping all data and just reinstall after?

Comment: You just re-install the OS over it to start again; you don't need to wipe it as the format will do that for you.  Thus you can install Lubuntu, try it as designed to be run (*instead of using both as I suggested that I personally prefer on my eeepc, but I'm hardly a newbie*), if you don't like it, install Xubuntu over it to see if that makes you happier.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150268/install-xubuntu-18-04-shortcut-showing-after-installing-the-same-xubuntu

Comment: Also, when I re install it shows that my PC does have Ubuntu even though I dont installed it

Comment: Xubuntu and Lubuntu are official flavors of Ubuntu, thus the "ubuntu" it sees on *re-install* could be Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-Budgie, ... (ie. any flavor which all share a common base)

Comment: when should I remove the bootable flash drive? After restart or before restart (after installation)

Comment: The system should tell you when you can remove the flash-drive; personally if the flash-drive-led is still lit, I wait until I recognize my machines is rebooting (when the thumb-drive led is unlit) and remove flash-drive then; ie. I do it during the restart.

Comment: what if my flash drive doesnt have LED?

Comment: I removed my flashdrive during the restart and it shows Failed to load ldlinux.c32, Boot failed